# Load dependencies in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins for building a few Java projects. I've come across a puzzle that I can't quite figure out: I have two projects, Project A and Project B. Project B depends on having A as a library. I don't want to build A before B. I want B to find the latest, promoted `Project A.jar` and copy it to a folder in the Project B workspace. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Jenkins to add a post build step to archive artifacts (your JAR file in this case)

Then use the copy artifact plugin in your second project to fetch the artifact https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

Comment: If your need grows to more than a few projects, in the Java world, managing dependencies is often achieved using a repository solution (maven, ivy, etc). The main alterantives are nexus, artifactory, archiva, compared here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix, but you can also go with a pure jenkins solution: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Maven+Repository+Server.